# jasper report(ireport) line/border not following to next group

Tags: jasper-reports

My report border is not displayed in continues way...
As shown in the image below i have 5 sections

- **Page header -** Logo and header content on each page
- **Group Header 1 -** displays employee details as it will be single row
- **Group Header 2 -** displays project details as it will be multiple row
- **Detail section -** displays project images
- **footer    -**      displays address on each page

The image below is showing up only 1st page wherein 2nd page(detail section) contains the images of the project.

> As you can see there is a gap at the border after group header 2 ->
>   footer

I've used line(element from palette) as a border, i've tried all types of stretch type but no luck :(

[image]

Can someone please help me out on how to resolve the issue.

Here is my JRXML code

http://pastebin.com/RbM51GHU

Comment: post relevant jrxml code..

Comment: placed the code in paste bin(updated in original post), as i was unable to post because of max lines limit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is since the `detail` band does not run to the end of your report.

Since you have `isStretchWithOverflow="true"` on certain textfield's we can not make the detail band to take whole page size (you would risk that it goes on next page if something in group band stretch's)

**The solution** is to add the two blue vertical border's in the **background band** and remove these from the detail, group and footer band.