# How to cover with a line all the detail space

Tags: jasper-reports

Good morning, I would appreciate your help with this. I am making a report as requested, but I can not make a line cover the entire area of empty detail, in the image that I put only have two details, what I'm looking for is that line on the left extends throughout the space in white framed in red without all the details, is it possible? What should I configure in the line, thanks in advance.

Use I report 5.6.0

[http://subirimagen.me/uploads/20190121164814.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p04Q5.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jasper report(ireport) line/border not following to next group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34743531/jasper-reportireport-line-border-not-following-to-next-group)

Answer (score 0):

I would have put this in a comment but I don't have enough points. If the page height is immutable, and the line needs to stay the same throughout the page, you can just put that line in a background band.

Comment: How could I make band divisions in the background band? to know from where the detail band starts from for example.